# How did Curwen become a necromancer?

Tags: h-p-lovecraft, the-case-of-charles-dexter-ward

I'm wondering whether Curwen was chosen by someone or something, or whether he became a necromancer by himself?

In the book there's this text in a letter from Curwen to Orne...

> Him whom we serve for yr eternall Power

... so there seems to be someone who "makes" necromancers. Does that someone select future necromancers or is there some "application procedure"?

Another quote that suggests that there's some instructor from a letter from Orne to Curwen:

> But I wou’d have you Observe what was tolde to us aboute tak’g Care whom to calle up

Answer (score 6):

I think it was Curwen's own research that turned up the method, as per this quote from a letter from Orne in chapter II (p35 in the version on [WikiSource](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Case_of_Charles_Dexter_Ward/Chapter_II))

> But I know what Imperfections were in the one rais'd up October last, and how many live Specimens you were forc'd to imploy before you hit upon the right Mode in the year 1766.

Where the "right Mode" is presumably the method of re-animating ("raising up") a corpse, and "hit upon" being "worked out the method by trial and error".

The quote you supply is a partial quote, the full being:

> My honour'd Antient friende, due Respects and earnest Wishes to Him whom we serve for yr eternall Power.

This comes from a letter putatively addressed to Orne by Curwen in chapter III, and I think is a reference to worship of the [outer gods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cthulhu_Mythos_deities#Outer_Gods), particularly with the mention of "YOGGE-SOTHOTHE" later in the letter. At the "time" (i.e. Curwen's time) of writing it was not uncommon to have some sort of sentiment praising (a) god in the text, such as is found in [this one](http://historymatters.gmu.edu/d/5787) written in 1631

> MOST LOVING & KIND FATHER & MOTHER, My humble duty remembered unto you, trusting in God you are in good health, & I pray remember my love unto my brother Joseph & thank him for his kindness that I found at his hand at London, . . . I know, loving father, & do confess that I was an undutiful child unto you when I lived with you & by you, for the which I am much sorrowful & grieved for it, trusting in God that he will guide me that I will never offend you so any more & I trust in God that you will forgive me for it.

I'm aware that this isn't quite the same as in the passage from Lovecraft. However, I can imagine that worship of a terrible/evil god of the sort portrayed by Lovecraft, would require devotion of the "bootlicking" kind - so a passage of devotion to the god in a letter or spoken speech would be expected between initiates of the worship.

Edited to add: According to [TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheCaseOfCharlesDexterWard), it is possible that the necromancers believe that Yog-Sothoth is in fact God/Jesus and refer to Yog-Sothoth as "He/Him" in a couple of places:

> ...gott me the sarcophagus of the Five Sphinxes from ye Acropolis where He whome I call’d up say’d it wou’d be...

Answer (score 6):

#### Curwen was one of the witches of Salem

In [Chapter 3](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Case_of_Charles_Dexter_Ward/Chapter_3), it is mentioned (emphasis in original):

> Certain documents by and about all of these strange matters were available...and included both harmless commonplaces such as land titles and bills of sale, and furtive fragments of a more provocative nature. There were four or five unmistakable allusions to them on the witchcraft trial records; as when one Hepzibah Lawson swore on July tenth, 1692, at the Court of Oyer and Terminen under Judge Hathorne, that "fortie Witches and the Blacke Man were wont to meet in the Woodes behind Mr. Hutchinson's house", and one Amity How declared at a session of August eighth before Judge Gedney that "Mr. C. B. (George Burroughs) on that Nighte putt the Divell his Marke upon Bridget S., Jonathan A., *Simon O.*, Deliverance W., *Joseph C.*, Susan P., Mehitable C., and Deborah B."

This seems to indicate that Curwen was one of the Salem witches, having been initiated into witchcraft by [George Burroughs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Burroughs), who was a real person executed for witchcraft (even if he didn't practice magic in real life, we are apparently supposed to believe that he did in the Mythos). Thus, it seems reasonable to suppose that Curwen become a necromancer, or at least a wizard, under the guidance of Burroughs in Salem, Massachusetts in 1692 by receiving the "Devil's mark". Simon Orne, Curwen's associate, apparently was initiated at the same time. This would have been several decades before the letter dated 1766 that bob1 mentioned, which in any event appears to represent Curwen at an advanced stage of magical development.

It is, of course, possible that Curwen had "dabbled" in the occult before this, possibly by reading books on magic. I believe we are, however, to see this as a pivotal moment in Curwen's life. The fact that one of Curwen's closest associates also underwent an initiation at the same time also draws emphasis to this event as important in their shared careers as necromancers.